# Why does assigning a JArray to a var fail when I call JsonConvert.DeserializeObject()?

Tags: json.net, json-deserialization, jsonconvert

On this line of code:

```
var arr = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JArray>(s);
```

...I am getting, "*Unable to cast object of type 'Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject' to type 'Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JArray'*."

I changed that line to this:

```
JArray arr = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JArray>(s);
```

...and got the same err msg.

I changed it to this:

```
var arr = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JObject>(s);
```

...and it wouldn't even compile.

The value of what has been read by the call (in string s) at this point is:

```
{"id":347745,"results":[{"iso_3166_1":"US","release_dates":[{"certification":"","iso_639_1":"","note":"","release_date":"1936-12-12T00:00:00.000Z","type":3}]}]}
```

All I want from it is the value for "certification"; In this case, the certification value is an empty string ("certification":"")

In context, the code is:

```
. . .
try
{
    var webRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(RESTStringToGetMPAARatingForMovieId);
    webRequest.Method = "GET";  
    var webResponse = (HttpWebResponse)webRequest.GetResponse();
    if ((webResponse.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK) && (webResponse.ContentLength > 0))
    {
        StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(webResponse.GetResponseStream());
        string s = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
        var arr = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JArray>(s);
        //JArray arr = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JArray>(s);
        //var arr = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JObject>(s);
        foreach (JObject obj in arr)
        {
            _currentMPAARating = (string)obj["certification"];
            . . .
        }
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show(string.Format("Status code == {0}, Content length == {1}",
          webResponse.StatusCode, webResponse.ContentLength));
    }    
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your JSON is not an array, it is an object which *contains* an array (`results`).  But it's actually more complicated than that: the `certification` string you seek is nested even further down inside a second `release_dates` array.

If you take your JSON and reformat it using a JSON validator/beautifier, it should become more clear:

```
{
  "id": 347745,
  "results": [
    {
      "iso_3166_1": "US",
      "release_dates": [
        {
          "certification": "",
          "iso_639_1": "",
          "note": "",
          "release_date": "1936-12-12T00:00:00Z",
          "type": 3
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

So to get the data you are looking for using regular `foreach` loops, you would need code like this:

```
var obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JObject>(s);
var resultArr = (JArray)obj["results"];
foreach (JObject resultObj in resultArr)
{
    var releaseDatesArr = (JArray)resultObj["release_dates"];
    foreach (JObject releaseDateObj in releaseDatesArr)
    {
        _currentMPAARating = (string)releaseDateObj["certification"];
        // ...
    }
}
```

Fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/SMzQTw

If all you need is the one item, here's a shortcut. Use the [`SelectToken`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JToken_SelectToken.htm) method with the recursive descent operator (`..`) like this:

```
var obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JObject>(s);
_currentMPAARating = (string)obj.SelectToken("..certification");
```

Fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/S1ScLO

But note the above will only return the first match.  If you are expecting multiple certifications, you can use [`SelectTokens`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JToken_SelectTokens.htm) (plural) instead:

```
var obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JObject>(s);
var ratings = obj.SelectTokens("..certification").Select(t => (string)t).ToList();
```

Fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/zyjNnJ

Comment: This looks like just what the sawbones ordered, but are those two dots in "..certification" to actually be taken literally?

Comment: Yep, the two dots are the *recursive descent operator*.  They are needed exactly as shown in the code.

Comment: I've added a fiddle to the answer to demonstrate.

Comment: Thanks; got it working! I'll bountify your answer ASAP. I have another one just posted if you want to take a look at that, too: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64036948/how-can-i-silently-bypass-a-rest-call-to-webrequest-getresponse-that-fails-40

Comment: If the returned json contains multiple "certification" values, does the code above take just the first one? For example, a subset of what is returned can be: "{"id":78,"results":[{"iso_3166_1":"US","release_dates":[{"certification":"R","iso_639_1":"","note":"","release_date":"1982-06-25T00:00:00.000Z","type":3}]},{"iso_3166_1":"FI","release_dates":[{"certification":"K-16","iso_639_1":"","note":"","release_date":"1982-10-01T00:00:00.000Z","type":3}]}," and that is just a subset - there are about a gazillion "certifications" in what's returned

Comment: Yes, `SelectToken` only returns the first match.  If you are expecting multiple, then use `SelectTokens` (plural) instead.  I've updated my answer.